# how to display progressbar during downloading video file from the server in to the iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented video play functionality in iphone.In which i am downloading video file from the server and then play.
But I want to display progress bar during downloading video file.For progressbar i need to calculate timing i don't know how to calculate time how much will take time for downloading video.

So please help me for this query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16454923/1704346

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the expected total file size in the following callback method of NSURLConnection's `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
   self.expectedTotalSize = response.expectedContentLength;
}
```

then in following callback method you can calculate how much data has been received:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
   self.recievedData += data.length;
}
```

And you can use UIProgressView to show current downloading status on the screen.

Comment: what are expectedTotalSize and receivedData?

Comment: They are two integer values you can save as properties. Choose a type that's appropriate, such as `long long`.

Comment: Does this still download if app goes in background ?