# Objective C: Downloading File With Progress Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, uiprogressview

I am trying to put a progress bar that syncs during the download that is happening.
My app now can download a file using with this codes...

```
    pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webaddress.com/pro/download/file.pdf"]];

    NSString *resourcePDFPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

    pdfFilePath = [resourcePDFPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];

    [pdfData writeToFile:pdfFilePath atomically:YES];
```

During the process of this code the app stopped during download, is it normal?
Now what I want is to put a progress bar during that stop time while downloading.

I tried looking into the codes I found online but I'm a bit confused, I think I need a step-by-step-well-explained reference.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking),**

here **progress is the UIProgressview**

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>//add to the header of class

-(void)downloadShowingProgress
{
   progress.progress = 0.0;

    currentURL=@"http://www.selab.isti.cnr.it/ws-mate/example.pdf";


    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentURL]];
    AFURLConnectionOperation *operation =   [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MY_FILENAME_WITH_EXTENTION.pdf"];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, NSUInteger totalBytesRead, NSUInteger totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        progress.progress = (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;

    }];

    [operation setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"downloadComplete!");

    }];
    [operation start];

}
```

**Using NSURLConnection**

```
-(void)downloadWithNsurlconnection
{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:currentURL];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self     startImmediately:YES];


}


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    progress.hidden = NO;
    [receivedData setLength:0];
    expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [receivedData appendData:data];
    float progressive = (float)[receivedData length] / (float)expectedBytes;
    [progress setProgress:progressive];


}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:    (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[currentURL stringByAppendingString:@".mp3"]];
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [receivedData writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
    progress.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: it says AFURLConnectionOperation is an undeclared identifier

Comment: Edited the answer.Have to include #import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
 in the class header

Comment: I tried it but it is not found. What framework should I use?

Comment: Added the link to framework in the title AFNetworking

Comment: What is expectedBytes?? I'm sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: as the name says .It is the total bytes to be recieved

Comment: No, I mean data type. It ok now it's working thanks! I declared it as long.

Comment: Honestly, I had no idea that NSURLResponse had an expectedContentLength property. Previously I was doing a HEAD request, then a GET request... It makes sense though, given how HTTP works...

Comment: and what if I am using a custom progress bar in response to the AFNetworking downloading. I have a block for progress in another view controller & that block is called from an object file but that progress is not working. could you help me out?

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh I think your question needs more information for it to be answered and I think it is better to raise it as a new question with details like the block for progress view and all

Comment: With AFNetworking code,where I will get the content of file? I need to save that in Document Directory!

Comment: I recommend the solution in this other thread, since `NSURLConnection` was deprecated back in iOS 9: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38063937/825644

Comment: @LithuT.V Progressbar is not smooth

Comment: @dinesharjani Just in case your link to swift example not objective-c

Answer (score 1):

Use ASIHTTPRequest.h class and ASINetworkQueue.h for downloading the file.

and use this code for progress bar

```
    request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:@"http://webaddress.com/pro/download/file.pdf];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:progressView];
    [request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
    request.shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground=YES;
    request.allowResumeForFileDownloads=YES;
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

this may help you

Comment: should I put this on button click of the "Download"?

Comment: yes you want to place this code in button click function...

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not normal, use asynchronous method to get the NSData.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be clear whether to make a synchronous call or asynchronous.
For mobile apps or any other app asynchronous is preferred one.

Once you are clear use **[NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** class to fetch the data from the URL.
Here is the [good tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/).

And for loading you can start progress while starting the request and stop it when you receive `connection:didFailWithError:` or `connectionDidFinishLoading:` delegate method.

Comment: How to download pdf file synchronously using NSURLConnection in swift @Inder Kumar Rathore