# how to display progress bar while downloading file from request response in Asihttp

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am downloading video file from response.
i want to display downloading progress bar of HUD-progress.
but how can i do that.
I am sending verify json to server and server verify that send back the video file bytes. i want to display how much percentage of downloading is done by using HUD-progreasse bar.

If i call `[request setDidReceiveDataSelector:@selector(request:didReceiveBytes:)];`  than it display how much bytes i got but it doesn't store the bytes into cache file ( it doesn't not store file into phone)

```
  ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://testing.io/dev.php/video/verifyReceipt"]];
  [request setPostValue:resultAsString forKey:@"verify"];// sending json in post 
[request setDidReceiveDataSelector:@selector(request:didReceiveBytes:)]; 
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:120];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
request.showAccurateProgress = YES;

[request startSynchronous];

 }
 -(void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
 {
[videoData appendData:data];// appending data with global NSmutabledata
  NSLog(@"data is %@",data);
   }

- (void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
//[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

// SAVED Video PATH
// Get the Document directory
NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
// Add your filename to the directory to create your saved video location
NSString* movLocation = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileName stringByAppendingString:@".mov"]];

if(request.responseStatusCode==200)
{
    [videoData writeToFile:movLocation atomically:NO];
    NSLog(@"in request done sucsessfully downlaod and store in database %d",request.responseStatusCode);
    [DBHelper savePurchaseId:fileName];
    [self movieReceived];
}
else{

      NSLog(@"in request downlaod and store in database failed %@",request.responseHeaders);

}
 }
     -(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
      {

NSLog(@"%@",request.error);

      }
```

Comment: still using ASIHTTP? Go for AFNetworking

Comment: @LithuT.V which one you recommend

Comment: Afnetworking for sure.It has active support and using blocks.Easy to implement.For your qn see this answer by me http://stackoverflow.com/a/16454923/1704346

Comment: @LithuT.V Okay i will try it

Comment: @LithuT.V I tried to append data with nsdata and after done i tried to store it into file but it wont get store..can you help me

Comment: @LithuT.V hwo to set post value in afnetworking which i set in my Asihttprequest..like this[request setPostValue:resultAsString forKey:@"verify"];

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623275/afnetworking-post-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fileUrl = string of URL to download a video.

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[fileUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:destPath append:NO];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        // Give alert that downloading successful.
        NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", destPath);

        /* To call delegate to response the result. */
        [self.target parserDidDownloadItem:destPath]; 

        HUD.detailsLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %i%%",[JGlobals getLocalvalue:@"Downloading"],100];
        [HUD hide:TRUE];
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        // Give alert that downloading failed
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

        /* To call delegate to response the result. */
        [self.target parserDidFailToDownloadItem:error];
        [HUD hide:TRUE];

    }];
    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
    {
         // Progress
         float totalProgress = (totalBytesWritten / (totalBytesExpectedToWrite * 1.0f) * 100);
         HUD.detailsLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading %i%%", MIN((int)(totalProgress), 99)];
     }];
    [operation start];
```

Comment: I made modification in your afnetworking code and it work for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of a method which might not be the right one, but it going to save you from writing a lot of code.

First set a normal `UIProgressView` instance as the download progress delegate like this

`[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:uiprogreeViewInstance];`

Now ASIHTTPRequest framework will take care of updating that progressview when the downloading will be taking place. ProgressView has a property named `progress`, which ranges from 0.0 to 1.0.

Now instantiate MBProgressHUD, add it as your subview where you want. Set the `progress` value of the `MBProgressHUD` instance to that of the `UIProgressView`. Hide the uiprogressview instance.

Comment: @Swap-IOS-Android Did you try this method?