# click a button in oneviewcontroller will progress the progressbar in anotherview controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

In my webview I set the download pop actionsheet while it find the anykind of file format.when i click the download button from the actionsheet then it download my file correctly from the url(using NSURLConnection and corresponding methods).Here i need the download progress is visible in another tableviewcontroller with progressbar.

```
 if ([[[currentURL lastPathComponent]pathExtension]isEqualToString:@"mp3"]||
     [[[currentURL lastPathComponent]pathExtension]isEqualToString:@"pdf"]||
     [[[currentURL lastPathComponent]pathExtension]isEqualToString:@"mp4"]){
     NSLog(@"downloadprogress method");
    NSLog(@"CURRENT URL:::%@",currentURL);

    [passArray addObject:currentURL];
     NSLog(@"PassArray::%@",passArray);
    [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",passArray.count]];




 }
```

here i add url when i click download button to passArray and pass it to my tableviewcontroller.But that is not working.

Detail Explaination:

---

1. I have tabbar with webviewcontroller and tableviewcontroller
2. in my webview i enter some pdf file url then it pop download
3. When i click my download button then the url of that pdf will downloding in tableviewcontroller even am in webviewcontroller
4. if i switch to tableviewcontroller then it display the proggressbar with download progress and corresponding percentage.

Here i done the first 2 steps.How can i do the 3 and 4?
Please help me......

Comment: Keep a reference to the download percentage and which row it's supposed to update. Then just update that progress bar with that percentage ? You will likely need a third part class (singleton perhaps) that holds a reference to the download.

Comment: when u click on tableview controller button then call one method [self sendSubViewToBack:yourVC.view] then it will go back and when u want to see ur table view then call [self bringSubViewToFront:yourVC.view];

Comment: could you please give me some link which explain details?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453655/objective-c-downloading-file-with-progress-bar

Comment: Ya I did this but this will download file on same viewcontroller.But I need to add my each download url to anotherviewcontroller i.e(tableviewcontroller) with download progressbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+(GlobalVariables *)shareObj{
static GlobalVariables *single=nil;

@synchronized(self){
    if (!single) {
        single=[[GlobalVariables alloc]init];
    }
}
    return single;
```

}

use singleton to shareobject...........