# How can I know the progress of image download?(Swift, UIKit)

Tags: ios, swift

### Question

I am trying to download a large image from the web with the code below. **I want to show how much download has been done using the progress bar**. Currently, it is only possible to know whether the download was successful or not.

```swift
func downloadBigImg() -> UIImage? {
    let imgURL = URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/1024")!
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imgURL) else { return nil }
        
    let image = UIImage(data:  data)
    return image
}
```

### What I did

[image]

Using asynchronous operation, the progress bar was raised during the download of the image. **But that Progress Bar is a fake**. It's not really a progress. **It just adds a very small number which isn't related to the actual progress.** When the image download is completed, it will be changed to 100%.

Comment: You will need to use a more sophisticated approach, `Data(contentsOf:)` can't provide any progress feedback.  If you are willing to use external frameworks, look at `SDWebImage` or `Kingfisher`

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060567/show-loading-percentage-of-image-download-from-url-with-swift

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show loading percentage of image download from url with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060567/show-loading-percentage-of-image-download-from-url-with-swift)

Comment: @DharaPatel Thank you. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @amadsalmon Thank you very much. I'll study about that!

Comment: You can use URLSessionDownloadDelegate