# Objective c: download a file with progress view

Tags: ios, xcode, url, afnetworking-2

Help me! I want download a file. And how display progress bar?

I read a lot of articles and I do not work, do not work, you can explain to me how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243910/how-to-display-progressbar-during-downloading-video-file-from-the-server-in-to-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get expected total file size in following callback method of NSURLconnection,

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
   expectedTotalSize = response.expectedContentLength;
}
```

then in the following callback method you can calculate how much data has been recieved,

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
   recievedData += data.length;
}
```

And you can use UIProgressView to show current downloading status on the screen.

Comment: Just a guess, but he tagged his question with afnetworking-2 so I'm assuming he wants to use that library.