# How to show downloading progress for a youtube video file

Tags: ios, video, youtube, download, progress

In my iOS app i am downloading a youtube video files to the iPhone using following code

```
LBYouTubeExtractor *extractor = [[[LBYouTubeExtractor alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:(@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@"), videoURL ]] quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge] autorelease];

   [extractor extractVideoURLWithCompletionBlock:^(NSURL *videoURLL, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {   

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURLL ];
                NSString *pathToDocs = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"video_%@.mp4"),videoURL];

                [videoData writeToFile:[pathToDocs stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename ] atomically:YES];

            });


 } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed extracting video URL using block due to error:%@", error);
        }
    }];
```

I want to show download progress in my app. How should i calculate the file size and percentage downloaded.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243910/how-to-display-progressbar-during-downloading-video-file-from-the-server-in-to-t

Comment: http://www.developers-life.com/progress-bar-download-file-on-iphone.html

Answer (score 0):

Declare bytesDownloaded and downloadSize as a float. If they are int you will need to cast them to a floating point value.

```
long double precent = (bytesDownloaded/downloadSize) * 100.0;
```